# What map API can we use now for AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps, air, maps, yahoo-maps

I'm using MapQuest for my AIR app (AS3) but I've read that it will be depreciate in the future.

Google Maps is depreciate for AS3
The Yahoo Maps has been deprecated for AS3.

So, my question is, which map API can we use now for AS3 ?

Comment: I'm using ModestMaps with OpenStreetMap.
See this [article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/interactive_maps.html).
You can download library [here](http://modestmaps.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using OpenScales. It still has some development activity and is a powerful mapping platform for AS3.

http://openscales.org/

You can use different mapping providers with it so you can get some great looking maps.